# Access 2007 VBA 6.5/7 + MySQLConnector Unicode 5.3 + Stored procedures

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, unicode, vba, mysql-connector

Does anyone have any advice on the following?

I have a MySQL UTF8 database

```
create schema utf8test;
use utf8test;

create table stringtable(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    thestring varchar(18) not null,
    primary key(id)
);

delimiter $$
create procedure `insertstring` (
    thestring VARCHAR(18) character set utf8
)
begin
insert into stringtable(thestring) values(thestring);
end$$
delimiter ;
```

And the following VBA subroutine

```
Private Sub Command_Click()

    Dim connection As ADODB.connection
    Dim command  As ADODB.command

    Set connection = New ADODB.connection
    connection.Open "DSN=TestUtf8"

    Set command = New ADODB.command
    With command
        .ActiveConnection = connection
        .CommandText = "insertstring"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .Parameters.("thestring") = Me.Text0
        .Execute
    End With


End Sub
```

Where Text0 is a textbox attached to the form the subroutine is called from.

I have two issues:

Firstly the line

```
        .Parameters.("thestring") = Me.Text0
```

appears to do a UTF16 to ANSI conversion at some point. So I wind up with garbage in the database for sanskrit characters and encoding errors for characters like ß.

I can make sort of make this go away by essentially calling WideCharToMultibyte and converting to UTF8 and sending the ANSI representation of the string and the bytes get interpreted on the server as UTF8. This technique probably has issues.

Secondly, in VBA, the space for VARCHAR parameters seems to get allocated in bytes not characters, so attempting to send a string of 10 ANSI represented UTF-8 ßs fails (20 bytes in total without BOM). I can hack around this as well by resizing the parameter

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("thestring", adVarChar, adParamInput, 18 * 3, utf8)
```

But that seems less than brilliant.

I've played with the DSN character set setting (leaving it blank, utf8, utf16) but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. (In fact with utf8 it appears to reencode the ANSI text again so I can send even fewer characters to the database).

Does anyone have any experience of this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've sort of worked around the problem.

I used the routines described [VB6, Activex and Unicode](http://paulturner.me/2008/09/visual-basic-6-activex-and-unicode/) to convert the strings into utf8 encoded byte arrays. Then forcibly replaced the adVarChar command parameters with those of type adBinary as follows

```
Public Sub AppendUTF8InputParameter(ByRef command As ADODB.command, ByRef name As String, ByRef value As String)
    Dim buf() As Byte
    Dim bufLen As Long
    buf = ConvertStringToUtf8Bytes(value)
    bufLen = UBound(buf) - LBound(buf) + 1
    With command
        .parameters.Delete name
        .parameters.Append .CreateParameter(name, adBinary, adParamInput, bufLen, buf)
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub AppendUTF8OutputParameter(ByRef command As ADODB.command, ByRef name As String)
    With command
        Dim size As Long
        size = 9 * .parameters(name).size
        .parameters.Delete name
        .parameters.Append .CreateParameter(name, adBinary, adParamOutput, size)
    End With
End Sub

Public Function ExtractUTF8StringParameter(ByRef command As ADODB.command, ByRef name As String)
    Dim strTemp As String
    With command
        strTemp = ConvertUtf8BytesToString(.parameters(name).value)
    End With
    ExtractUTF8StringParameter = strTemp
End Function
```

The 9 fudge factor is there because the size of an OUT VARCHAR(18) stored procedure parameter reported by

```
.parameters(name).size
```

is 6 when the DSN is set up with UTF8. So 3 to get the original size back and then a further 3 because in the worst case we're going to need 3 bytes per character for MySQL's UTF8 unicode representation.

Comment: The strings returned in ADODB.RecordSets are also an issue. From what I understand the bytes returned from the server get interpreted as ANSI and then converted from ANSI to UTF16 for you. My work around is to take that UTF16 convert it back to ANSI and then feed those bytes into the functions linked above. It doesn't appear to be possible to use GetChunk on the VARCHAR columns to get at the raw data.

Comment: Slight problem with the above implementation; Don't delete the parameters rather simply amend their properties.